# Xubuntu 22.04 - want a simple script to remember audio volume between sessions

Tags: sound, 22.04, xubuntu, shutdown, startup

This is similar to a previous question:-
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bk5czo/audio_volume_levels_not_remembered_after_reboot/

But I didn't want to try that solution as it seemed like fixing it as a bug or setup error and not comprehensively explained.

==

My audio is a home cinema and easily capable of causing hearing injuries and/or tinnitus. Given the very foreseeable safety risk, I disliked that my OS is *at all* able to just forget the volume between sessions, but I have managed this by keeping the hardware volume turned very low and using a systemd service and shell script to set the software volume to 50% on startup. The only command in it is:-

pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 50%

What I would like is to improve this by making a simple shutdown script to write the "last good" volume into a text file, and then change my startup script to set the volume to that last good volume. And I could probably work out for myself how to add some other logic, e.g. so that it checks it's under 50%.

Comment: Doesn't it remember the volume out of the box? That's how it always worked for me, on several different distributions.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat indeed it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From other posts it seems it is more complicated than that sink-volume is already a system-wide variable. But I did find this command to write the current volume to a file:-

[NAME] is where I have some path specific to my user

pacmd list-sinks|grep -A 15 '* index'| awk '/volume: front/{ print $5 }' | sed 's/[%|,]//g' > /home/[NAME]/lastvolume.txt

So I can then make 4 things: a startup script, a startup service, a shutdown script, a shutdown service.

**1. shutdown script - checkvolume.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
pacmd list-sinks|grep -A 15 '* index'| awk '/volume: front/{ print $5 }' | sed 's/[%|,]//g' > /home/[NAME]/lastvolume.txt
exit 0
```

**2. shutdown service - checkvolume.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Records the last volume on logout, reboot, or shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/home/[NAME]/checkvolume.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**3. startup script - volume.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
vol=$(cat /home/[NAME]/lastvolume.txt)
pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ $vol%
exit 0
```

**4. startup service - volume.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=to set the volume to 50% on startup

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/[NAME]/volume.sh start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The two scripts must be made executable with the chmod +x command

The two service files I must save into /etc/systemd/system

They must be named ending in .service

And each one I must enable using this command

sudo systemctl enable checkvolume.service

sudo systemctl enable volume.service

==

Although the scripts work as intended during a session, on boot the file lastvolume.txt is overwritten blank and the volume is reset to 100.

So it seems that during shutdown, my pulseaudio is setting the volume to a nul value. My script then overwrites the number inside the file with nothing. And then on startup either my script can't set the value to nul so it becomes 100, or my pulseaudio resets it to 100 after the script has run.

I then disabled the two services with

sudo systemctl disable checkvolume.service

sudo systemctl disable volume.service

and instead went in the UI to Applications > Settings > Session and Startup
and created two new entries here pointing to the scripts

This seems to have worked for the startup script but not the shutdown script.
At shutdown the lastvolume.txt file storing the variable is not overwritten blank, but also is not overwritten with the last good volume.

I suppose scripts placed here might be run at a different point in the PC's startup and shutdown sequences, compared with the systemd services. To me not being a power-user this is somewhat opaque, and I worry in case this whole interface might be left over on my PC from an earlier version of the OS.

I will carry on trying to make the shutdown script run correctly. If this can run before pulseaudio (or perhaps alsa?) resets the volume to nul then hopefully I can have what I want

In the Session and Startup interface, I have tried setting the shutdown script (checkvolume.sh) on Shutdown, Logout, Restart and this doesn't seem to make it work

I looked at how Xfce handles shutdown scripts and it seems to be difficult. The UI interface I mentioned above either isn't working or is running the scripts with a shutdown/reset/logoff Hook at (for me) a wrong stage relative to pulseaudio shutting down. Apart from this I think there are the options to create a wrapper script in /usr/local/bin/xfce4-session or to edit to change /usr/bin/X11/xfce4-session but the people who mention those approaches didn't happen to explain enough for my needs, for example what a wrapper script is.

==

In Applications > Settings > Keyboard I also tried to add the command to write the volume to lastvolume.txt onto the end of the keyboard commands that raise and lower the volume, using an ampersand & - but this didn't work. I could perhaps make the volume key call a little script if concatenation isn't supported in this interface.

In the end yes that is what I did. I made two more scripts and used the Keyboard interface to bind them to the volume up and volume down keys. I dislike this as it is workaround-y and will not record volume changes other than with my keyboard buttons, such as those made within software or a terminal command. But nearly always I use just the keyboard buttons so this should work OK for me unless someone has a neater solution.

**1. volumeup.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5%
pacmd list-sinks|grep -A 15 '* index'| awk '/volume: front/{ print $5 }' | sed 's/[%|,]//g' > /home/dave/lastvolume.txt
exit 0
```

**2. volumedown.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%
pacmd list-sinks|grep -A 15 '* index'| awk '/volume: front/{ print $5 }' | sed 's/[%|,]//g' > /home/dave/lastvolume.txt
exit 0
```